# Why Doesn't the Diamond Arrow in this Tikz Code Example Work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am attempting to learn Tikz via [this MIT tutorial](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/project/latex/tutorial_latex_tikz.pdf). Early in the tutorial the author provides the following code:

```
\draw[help lines, thick] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw[->,>=diamond,thick] (0,0) -- (1,2);
```

**Question**:

The `>=diamond` part of the second `\draw` command is causing

> ! Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip
> kind 'diamond'

Why is this happening?

Comment: I woult put this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation points: If the Tikz manual seems daunting at first (although it’s less daunting than it looks) [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tutorials) has some pretty good tutorials as an introduction. There is [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package#Introduction), which is a general tutorial, there’s also [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing#Grids), which is a 5 part series, and [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/

Answer (score 11):

Because TikZ by default doesn't define an arrow tip named `diamond`.

To access the `diamond` tip you need to load the now deprecated library `arrows`. However, because that library is considered deprecated, I'd instead load the `arrows.meta` library, and use the `Diamond` tip.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, thick] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw[->,>=Diamond,thick] (0,0) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any recommendations for an up-to-date general Tikz tutorial?

Comment: @Gary I don't really know what's out there, so can only suggest chapters 2-6 of the TikZ manual.

Comment: @Gary: The way to learn TikZ is to read the manual. The manual is huge, but it is well structured. You only need to read what is relevant for a specific drawing. There is even a tutorial/introduction directly in the manual.

Comment: With `arrows.meta`, you can write `\draw[-{Diamond},thick]` for something more compact.

Comment: @Crazymoomin The `-arrowtipname` syntax doesn't require `arrows.meta`, if that's what you meant. And if you'll forgive some further nitpicking, the `{}` are only needed if you add options in `[]` to the arrow tip. :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know about the second one, I think it's just a good habit to keep them because you'll forget when you do add options!